# Use SELECT as value for JOIN

Tags: sql, select, join

I have table `ItemPropertyValue` with unique `ID` and `PropertyID`

```
ID IDProperty Value ItemID
1  1            1    5 
2  2            2    6
3  3            2    10
4  4            2    15
```

And another table called `PropertyCategory`

```
IDProperty  Value  Name
1           1      First Option
1           2      Second Option
2           1      Another option
```

What I want - it's to select `PropertyID` from first table `ItemPropertyValue` where `ItemID = 10`  and then `join` with `second table PropertyCategory`

So I have smth like this:

```
IDProperty  Value  Name
1           1      First Option
1           2      Second Option
2           1      Another option
```

I tried this but there is an error. No such column as PropertyID

```
    SELECT * FROM PropertyCategory JOIN 
    (SELECT ItemPropertyValue.IDProperty AS PropertyID
    WHERE ItemPropertyValue.IDItem = '10') 
    ON PropertyCategory.IDProperty = PropertyID
```

How can I do it?

MS SQLServer if any

Comment: Please specify what DB you are using

Comment: It would help if your `WHERE` query filtered on a column that actually exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use table alias:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM PropertyCategory 
    JOIN 
        (SELECT ItemPropertyValue.IDProperty AS PropertyID 
            WHERE ItemPropertyValue.IDItem = '10') as T
        ON PropertyCategory.IDProperty = T.PropertyID
```

Answer (score 3):

Try Aliasing the subselect

```
SELECT * FROM PropertyCategory JOIN 
(SELECT ItemPropertyValue.IDProperty AS PropertyID
WHERE ItemPropertyValue.IDItem = '10') a
ON PropertyCategory.IDProperty = a.PropertyID
```

Additionally, this would do well as a regular join with the filtrating happening in the outer `WHERE` clause, like

```
SELECT *
FROM PropertyCategory
JOIN ItemPropertyValue ON PropertyCategory.IDProperty = ItemPropertyValue.IDProperty
WHERE ItemPropertyValue.IDProperty = '10'
```

Finally, if you happen to be using SQL Server and *really* want to do it in a subselect-type of statement, I'd suggest checking out `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY` for such an application.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for something like

```
SELECT * FROM ItemPropertyValue JOIN PropertyCategory
```

ON ItemPropertyValue.IDProperty = PropertyCategory.IDProperty 
WHERE ItemPropertyValue.ItemID=10

You can restrict to couple of field in your SELECT by replacing the * with fields.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing fine, just add alias to table name and it will work

```
SELECT * FROM PropertyCategory a JOIN 
        (SELECT ItemPropertyValue.IDProperty AS PropertyID
        WHERE ItemPropertyValue.IDItem = '10')  b
        ON a.IDProperty = b.PropertyID
```